# I messed up the `/usr/bin/python3` in Ubuntu 18.04, how can I install it back

Tags: 18.04, python3

I was trying to linking different versions of python3 and now I messed up the `/usr/bin/python3` and `/usr/bin/python3.6`. Now I have the `/usr/bin/python2` and `/usr/local/bin/python3.7` still working. 
If I type `python3` or `python3.6`, I got

```
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

But when I run

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

It says

```
python3 is already the newest version (3.6.7-1 ~ 18.04)
```

The gnome-terminal is also not working due to the absence of python3. I am using the Xterm now. What can I do to recover that?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.6`? That might help know how to fix it.

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6`
`/usr/bin/python3.6 -> /usr/bin/python3`. Well it looks like a deadlock

Comment: Good! It's a loop. `sudo rm /usr/bin/python3.6` and the command in my answer shoud solve it.

Comment: Do you know if there's any difference between python3 & python3.6? I think these are the same. Because if you installed py3.6 then it seems to be updating py3. Therefore writing all files on the same path. Try installing on different directories.

Answer (score 1):

This will recreate the symlink from python3 to python3.6 and reinstall the binary python3.6. It might be enough or not, depending on how much you messed the python package.

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3.6
sudo apt-get install --reinstall --download-only python3.6
```

That will download the deb package to `/var/cache/apt/archives`

Create a new directory somewhere, where you are going to unpack the .deb file and get the missing binary:

```
dpkg -X /var/cache/apt/archives/python3.6_3.6.9-1~18.04_amd64.deb /tmp/justforthis
cp -a /tmp/justforthis/usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin
```

Comment: it says `py3compile: Too many levels of symbolic links` and 
```
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure): installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error
```

Comment: I forgot to add python3 to the `apt-get install --reinstall`. Can you try it now?

Comment: It says `Internal Error, No file name for python3-minimal:amd64`

Comment: Ok ... then just `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3` (but please remove first the `/usr/bin/python3.6` because it should be a binary and it became a symlink pointing to a another symlink).

Comment: it still says erros were encountered while processing: python3-minimal. I didn't put in the python3-minimal in the command

Comment: `/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: py3compile: not found`, `dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure): installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error `

Comment: Ok, one more try. I just updated the answer.

Comment: Cope python3? In /tmp/justforthis/usr/bin/, there are py3clean, py3compile, py3versions, python3, python3m. But the python3 and python3m are shown in red

Comment: Sorry, wrong package. Check the answer (it's python3.6). I have a newer version, that's why.

Comment: Now there are only `pdb3.6`, `pydoc3.6` and `pygettex3.6` in `/tmp/justforthis/usr/bin/`. And there is no error executing all your code